# I know that the binary and hexadecimal are useful, but what are the point of other bases, for example base 12?

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-algebra-systems

I know about the uses of binary and hexadecimal, but what are the uses of other bases, for example base 12? (or duodecimal)

Comment: In base 12, a dozen eggs becomes 10.

Comment: Mostly they're useful for understanding the arbitrariness of base ten. (That being said, people [have built ternary computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun)...)

Comment: @GerryMyerson That sounds like reason enough to switch to a more sensible system, like base 6, where your dozen becomes 20 instead.

Comment: There is nothing gained by forbidding other bases.

Answer (score 1):

We use base 60 for time and for degrees.

I don't know any practical use of base 12, but it would certainly be nicer than base 10. For instance, in base 12 the number 1/3 is not periodic: you have $$1/3=4/12=4\times 12^{-1}=0.4_{12}.$$

Comment: This is the exact reason for bases 12 and 60: the ancient mathematics did not know how to deal with fractions, but with base 12 you have integer numerators for all the fractions with denominators with 3 and 4 as factors. In base 60 you have the same result with denominators multiple of 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: @N74 I don't think "didn't know how to deal with fractions" is a fair characterization; see Plimpton 322, which seems to suggest that $1 + 24/60 + 51/60^2 + 10/60^3 \approx \sqrt 2$

Comment: They certainly did know how to deal with fractions. The reason for base 60 was due to its convenience in scientific computations. Much like we use binary today due to its convenience with digial representations of numbers.

Comment: @pjs36 still they did not use the zero or the decimal point and all the fractions had base 60 (or multiples). They surely got amazing results but limited by the "refuse" of numbers incompatible with the chosen base. Probably they thought $1/7$ as "irrational" as $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion between different bases turns out to be a useful way to talk about various pathological functions in analysis.

Some examples of this:

- The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $c$: the base-2 expansion of $c(x)$ is closely related to the base-3 expansion of $x$.
- The [Conway base-13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) $f$: the base-$10$ expansion of $f(x)$ is closely related to the base-$13$ expansion of $x$ (or, more generally, you could have a version of it where the base-$k$ expansion of $f(x)$ was closely related to the base-$(k+3)$ expansion of $x$, for any $k \geq 2$).

Answer (score 0):

The theory for developing and computing the binary or hexadecimal representation of a number applies equally well to other bases. They may or may not be useful. If some species of alients have 12 fingers they may find base 12 useful.

Having too large base has one practical difficulty: finding names for the numbers and remembering them. Too small a base makes even a moderately small number requiring large number of digits to write down.

Civil engineers may have the right math that tell us how deep a foundation has to be to build a 500-storey building. Will we build it?

Comment: All bases except base 1 offer essentially the same efficiency when it comes to number of digits required for writing a number down.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: I don't understand what you mean by 'same efficiency'. I will make my meaning clearer: The number of days in a year can be written in base 10 using 3 digits, and  the same in base 2 requires 9 digits (or bits).

Comment: I mean that the difference in number of digits required between two different bases (not equal to 1) is negligible compared to the magnitude of the number being represented.

Comment: I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Their use is precisely the use you have for base $10$: they provide a means of representing numbers concretely. The only difference between  $17_{10}$ and $10_{17}$ is that you are accustomed to the former representation rather than the latter to represent the number of periods in the quoted symbol ".................".